# Change the correlation coefficient of two signals

Tags: arrays, matlab, statistics, trigonometry

I have an algorithm that takes two sinusoidal vectors as input. I have to plot the performance of this algorithm by increasing the correlation of input signals.

My question is that how can I increase the correlation coefficient?

Right now I use some code like this,

```
fs = 8000; 
t = (0 : 1 / fs : 1).';
x1 = cos(2 * pi * t * 300);
for i = linspace(0,1,20)
    j = j + 1;
    x2 = cos(2 * pi * (t + i / 300) * 300);
    rho12 = corrcoef(x1,x2);
    c(j) = rho12(1,2);
    error_out(j) = algorithm(x1,x2);
end
plot(c,error_out)
```

And it gives me this,

[image]

First of all, is it right to change correlation with phase?

Secondly, how can I avoid repeated correlation coefficients?

**Edit**

Changing `i` to `linspace(0,.5,20)` seems to remove repeated coefficients.

Comment: What is `rho12` supposed to do?

Comment: @DaveKielpinski, thanks for your attention. I corrected it, `rho12 = corrcoef(x1,x2);` and since it gives a `2x2` matrix, I choose the `rho12(1,2)` element.